# Is the length of the annotation important for guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have the following line in my ".cfg" file...

```
*.*.HM_EVALUATION_RESPONSE_DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = "Random_Table_Name";
```

but when I inject this into my code via Guice annotation

```
@Inject
@Named("HM_EVALUATION_RESPONSE_DATABASE_TABLE_NAME")
private String tableName;
```

I got the following error

```
no implementation of com.google.inject.names.Named(value=HM_EVALUATION_RESPONSE_DATABASE_TABLE_NAME) is bound
```

but when I changed the above line in my ".cfg" file to

```
*.*.HM.EVALUATION_RESPONSE.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = "Random_Table_Name";
```

It worked. So my question is does Guice have some kind on the length restrictions for annotated names. Also i have not used previous annotated name anywhere in my config file.

Here is the code for my config binder.

```
Appconfig.initialize(APP_NAME, null , args);
```

*args has --domain=build/private * which contains my configuration files

```
final AppconfigBinder appConfigBinder = new AppconfigBinder(binder());
appConfigBinder.bindPrefix(*);
```

One more thing I would like to point out, all other annotated names in the config file bound to a object which were less than 20 characters

Comment: This is *weird*. Good question.

Comment: @chrylis no, it's not a good question. It could be a good question if there were any extra information on how to properly reproduce this issue, because Guice has no ".cfg" file by default. So telling how the mapping between the two is done would make this a good question.

Comment: What is AppconfigBinder?

Comment: Its an amazon specific, so i cannot add more code, but just assume that its a wrapper for properties binder

Comment: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Sometimes it happens that your build folder does not have update cfg file. Have you checked if build folder has updated contents?